# Why do I get a different date after converting an Access query to SQL Server?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access, vba

I have an Access query...

```
[Net Weight Tracking].[Start Time], [Net Weight Tracking].[Stop Time], Hour([start time]) AS HrStart, Hour([stop time]) AS HrStop, [date] & " " & [start time] AS Start, IIf([hrstart]>12 And [hrstop]<12,[date]+1 & " " & [stop time],[date] & " " & [stop time]) AS Stop
```

...that yields the following result:

[image: Result of the Access Query]

It reflects the date I expect, `3/21/1932`.

I converted the Access query to T-SQL...

```
DATENAME(hour, dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].[Start Time])+':'+DATENAME(MI,[Net Weight Tracking].[Start Time]) AS StartTime,DATENAME(hour, dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].[Stop Time])+':'+DATENAME(MI,[Net Weight Tracking].[Stop Time]) AS StopTime, 
                       DATEPART(HH, dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].[Start Time]) AS HrStart, DATEPART(HH, dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].[Stop Time]) 
                      AS HrStop, (dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].Date) +''+ dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].[Start Time] AS Start, CASE WHEN DATEPART(HH, dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].[Start Time])>12 AND DATEPART(HH, dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].[Stop Time])<12 THEN  (dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].Date + 1) +''+ dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].[Stop Time] ELSE (dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].Date + '' + dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].[Stop Time]) END AS STOP
```

..., but it unexpectedly yields the following result:

[image: Result of the SQL Server Query]

If I am using the date `3/21/1932`, why does the SQL Server query's result show `3/19/1932`?

Comment: Access uses 1899-12-30 as their "zero date" while SQL Server uses 1900-01-01, and that could certainly account for a difference of exactly two days. How did you get the data to SQL Server? Did you check the actual data in the table? What is the data type in SQL Server?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I used the Upsizing Wizard from Access to move all the tables into SQL and the datatype is DateTime in SQLServer, Yes i did a select * on the main table and the date is 1932-03-21 00:00:00.000

Comment: And what about the start time / stop time columns? What data type are those, and what do they contain? I get the correct date output. Where exactly are you seeing 3/19/1932? In Excel or a linked query in Access?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Your right bud the Start time is 1899-12-30 15:53:00.000 and stop time is 1899-12-30 01:55:00.000 and these are of DateTime data type as well.

Comment: With those values I can't get the query to run. But the query looks enormously complex for what you seem to be trying to do anyway. Why do you have the start date as date only and the start time as time only (on the wrong date)? Why isn't your table data just `1932-03-21T15:53`? And how could something start at 3 in the afternoon and run until 2 in the morning on the same day? The query also seems to make the assumption that nothing could ever last more than 12 hours - is this enforced somehow?

Comment: The problem is partly that your imported data is on 1899-12-30 instead of 1900-01-01, partly because those times should be part of the date data and not separate, and partly because your query is extremely convoluted. If you can't fix the table design *and* the data, see [this SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6d5d8/1).

Comment: @AaronBertrand the start date and start are broken down into two different entities, i was also wondering why it is not 1932-03-21T15:53 <- this is what i exactly wanted. Yea the 12 hours is enforced within th application, there is an access application that is used for tracking the net weight of items, the project assigned to me is to migrate this application to c# and sql backend. So i am now struggling at the sql backend once this is fixed i shouldn't have any problems of displaying this date in my c# application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67871/discussion-between-hackgod555-and-aaron-bertrand).

Comment: @AaronBertrand much appreciated, so this sql fiddle is that free?? Its a pretty cool website.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have another issue, i need to calculate the [Runtime (Min)] i am calculating the value by doing a DateDiff(Minute, Start, Stop) but i am not able to just use start and stop i need to add in the code you provided when i do that i am getting incorrect syntax error. Why can't we use the alias as an Column in SQl it would be soo much easier -> DateDiff(minute, strat, stop)

Comment: Use a subquery or a CTE. `WITH x AS (SELECT alias = [complex expression]) SELECT * FROM x WHERE alias > foo;`

Comment: @AaronBertrand I tried using subquery, similar to your other approach but getting an Incorrect syntax error in sqlfiddle -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6d5d8/4

Comment: @AaronBertrand i forgot to add a comma now it works but i am getting -838 minutes the expected result is 602

Comment: It's because you've changed `Stop` at the outer scope. The `DATEDIFF` expression at that scope is using the inner version, before the day was added to it. [You need to nest again](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48867d/1).

Comment: @AaronBertrand appreciate it but why can't we just use the alias as a column, life would be soo much easier just one simple code, DateDiff(minute, start, stop) since start and stop are already calculated before. but now i know i need to learn more on subquery and cte.

Comment: Just the way SQL works, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AaronBertrand, using his sql code from SQL Fiddle, i was able to accomplish what i needed.

**Answer**

```
DATENAME(hour, dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].[Start Time])+':'+DATENAME(MI,[Net Weight Tracking].[Start Time]) AS StartTime,DATENAME(hour, dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].[Stop Time])+':'+DATENAME(MI,[Net Weight Tracking].[Stop Time]) AS StopTime, 
                       DATEPART(HH, dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].[Start Time]) AS HrStart, DATEPART(HH, dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].[Stop Time]) 
                      AS HrStop, DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, CONVERT(TIME, [Start Time])), [Date]) AS Start, CASE WHEN DATEPART(HH, dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].[Start Time])>12 AND DATEPART(HH, dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].[Stop Time])<12 THEN  (DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, CONVERT(TIME, [Stop Time])), [Date]) + 1)  ELSE DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, CONVERT(TIME, [Stop Time])), [Date]) END AS STOP
```

To View the result click this-> [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLnw9.jpg)